# SQL SELECT multiple keys/values

Tags: sql, jpql, psql

I've got a table `PERSON_PROPERTIES` that resembles the following :

```
|   ID   |   KEY    |    VALUE     |   PERSON_ID   |
|    1   |   fname  |    robert    |       1       |
|    2   |   lname  |    redford   |       1       |
|    3   |   fname  |    robert    |       2       |
|    4   |   lname  |    de niro   |       2       |
|    5   |   fname  |    shawn     |       3       |
|    6   |   nname  |    redford   |       3       |
```

I would like to `SELECT` (in JPQL or in PSQL) the `PERSON_ID` that matches the given `fname` and `lname`.

I've tried

```
`SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES t0
WHERE ((((t0.key = 'fname')
AND (t0.value    = 'robert'))
AND ((t0.key     = 'lname')
AND (t0.value    = 'redford'))))`
```

but it returns me no value.

I've also tried

```
`SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES t0
WHERE ((((t0.key = 'fname')
AND (t0.value    = 'robert'))
OR ((t0.key      = 'lname')
AND (t0.value    = 'redford'))))`
```

but this way it returns me all values. I don't know how to turn the query properly for it to give me only value `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES
group by PERSON_ID
having sum(case when key = 'fname' and value = 'robert' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when key = 'lname' and value = 'redford' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Groupy by the person and select only those having both values.

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice and succinct.

Comment: I would've never thought to do it by myself. Just works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be with subselect (caution, it's MS SQL 2012)

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES
WHERE [Key] = 'fname' AND value = 'robert'
AND PERSON_ID in 
(SELECT PERSON_ID FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES WHERE [Key] = 'lname' AND value = 'redford')
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74e0d/5)

Comment: +1 for another good idea :). I myself want to avoid overuse of SUM and CASE

Comment: I tried this in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74e0d/1/0). It doesn't seem to work with the new data in input.

Answer (score 1):

Along with some colleagues we came to this answer :

```
SELECT p.PERSON_ID
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES p
WHERE (p.key = 'fname' AND p.value = 'robert')
OR (p.key = 'lname' AND p.value = 'redford')
GROUP BY p.PERSON_ID
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: I am the OP :). And it wouldn't match "robert whatever" due to the `GROUP BY p.PERSON_ID HAVING count(*) = 2` operator. Adding `GROUP BY t.id HAVING count(*) = X` for X parameters you put in your query forces the results you seek to be present X times to be selected. It does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`SELF JOIN` also does the trick. `DISTINCT` for duplicate `person_id`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.PERSON_ID
FROM PERSON_PROPERTIES a JOIN PERSON_PROPERTIES b ON a.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID
WHERE a.the_key = 'fname' AND a.value = 'robert'
AND b.the_key = 'lname' AND b.value = 'redford';
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/983ae/1)

Answer (score 0):

OK I will be marking this as the correct answer. The only thing I did was modified it a bit

```
SELECT Y.*, M.* FROM wp_postmeta as Y JOIN wp_postmeta AS M USING (`post_id`) 
 WHERE (Y.meta_key = 'agam_post_options_year' AND Y.meta_value = 2013) 
AND (M.meta_key = 'agam_post_options_month' AND M.meta_value BETWEEN 0 AND 12 ) 
GROUP BY Y.meta_value, M.meta_value ORDER BY M.meta_value+0 DESC
```

So I get that DESC order..  however..  I noticed that it does not duplicates results... I had two posts with the same year and same month...  now I don't see it...  is there anything there that's preventing this ?